# How to click on each marker of google map present on any website using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How to do the Automation testing of any Google map. I have a map in my project/application, now I want to click on each markers.

Comment: What have you tried, how did it not work? Have you tried another browsers? Did you get any exceptions? Which exceptions? Can you please show us your code? In which language do you write your tests?

Comment: By the way, I have just tried it, it's not that hard once you find a way to find the markers. The best way is probably their `src` attribute (`By.cssSelector("img[src*='markerTransparent.png']")` worked for me). The whole page is just a lot of html/js and every marker is its own element. You can do it!

Answer (score 6):

Since you have no experience with WebDriver, I'm going to give you the answer you want (and not the one you need which is *"Go look at WebDriver manual and tutorials."*).

Java example:

```java
// opens up Chrome, but you can use any other browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
// goes to GMaps page and searches for "Washington"
driver.get("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Washington");
// clicks the only marker on the page
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src*='markerTransparent.png']")).click();
// don't forget to kill the browser or else you'll have neverending chromedriver.exe processes
driver.quit();
```

Now, you need to take a step back, look at WebDriver, choose a language in which you want to write your tests, go through the API and some examples, then try to implement your tests and if something goes astray, feel free to post another question with a particular issue (just make sure to search for it first).

Answer (score 0):

You can click on each marker by locating that marker using ID.

Here is one script which I wrote to click on marker of google maps

```
d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

d.get 'http://maps.google.com'

d.find_element(:id, 'gbqfq').click

d.find_element(:id, 'gbqfq').send_keys 'hdfc bank pune'

d.find_element(:id, 'gbqfb').click

d.find_element(:id, 'mtgt_J.1000').click
```